# Why doesn't PL/SQL respect privileges granted by Roles?

Tags: oracle, plsql

When executing a PL/SQL block, any privileges granted to roles are ignored. Instead you must give specific users specific grants to run it. If I want to give DBAs access to a package or a function or a procedure, I can't give the DBA role a grant. I have to give a grant to each user in the DBA role, I have to remove the user's grant if they cease to be a DBA, and I have to add the grant to any new DBA.

I find this very hard to maintain.

My question is why does PL/SQL work this way? What design considerations did Oracle make to decide that this is how Roles and PL/SQL should work together? I've been unable to find an answer that isn't "that's just the way it is".

Comment: [Tom kyte has a likely explanation](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1065832643319): it could lead to a dependency chain (role affected to role affected to role...) that would be hard to maintain.

Comment: This is one of the reasons why you may want to designate a special _functional_ user ID to compile function, procedures and packages.

Comment: What you're describing doesn't seem to make sense.  Or at least you're leaving out some important requirements.  If you have a definer's rights stored procedure, you can grant access to that procedure to a user via a role and that user has all the privileges they need to call it.  The user wouldn't be able to create their own stored procedure that calls this procedure but there are generally many users that need to call procedures and few that need to define their own.  Having production objects owned by human users generally makes a mess of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otherwise if you drop a role then the PL/SQL package would become INVALID in some cases (without having the option to re-compile).

`DROP ROLE ...` is a DCL (Data Control Language) statement. Looks like Oracle decided: "A PL/SQL package shall not become INVALID by a DCL statement"

Comment: DROP ROLE is Data Definition Language, I think. Modifying the privileges of either a role or a user is DCL, so I think that part of the answer is not correct.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be fighting over Invokers rights vs Definers rights.

From [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/subprograms.htm#LNPLS00809):

> During a server call, when a DR unit is pushed onto the call stack,
>   the database stores the currently enabled roles and the current values
>   of CURRENT_USER and CURRENT_SCHEMA. It then changes both CURRENT_USER
>   and CURRENT_SCHEMA to the owner of the DR unit, **and enables only the
>   role PUBLIC**. (The stored and new roles and values are not necessarily
>   different.) When the DR unit is popped from the call stack, the
>   database restores the stored roles and values. In contrast, when an IR
>   unit is pushed onto, or popped from, the call stack, the values of
>   CURRENT_USER and CURRENT_SCHEMA, and **the currently enabled roles do
>   not change**

So if you want Oracle to "respect the privileges granted by roles", then perhaps you want to use Invokers rights ( AUTHID CURRENT_USER clause)

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a combination of laziness and the `SET ROLE` command.

I disagree that it's not allowed because of complex dependencies.  Oracle already manages complex dependencies.  And in 12c it is possible to grant a role to an object.

I think the real reason why objects don't inherit the roles of the user is because of the `SET ROLE` command.  It's possible for a user to be assigned a role but to turn it on and off within a session.  That's a silly feature and I've never seen it used.  But theoretically it would require recompiling within the same session or transaction, which would be really confusing.

Comment: @Offtopic. The `SET ROLE` is handy when you need 2 factor authentication. (When role is protected by the password). User knows it's own password and the 2nd role password is "hard-coded" in the application. Then even if the user is able to connect to the database via SQLPlus he can not do anything there as he can not enable application specific role. PS: good point.

Comment: @ibre5041 That makes sense.  However, that would be [two-step authentication, not two-factor authentication](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/41939).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am not understanding something correctly here, because I have done what you say can't be done.  In fact, the Oracle documentation says it can be done.  Look at the section on Procedure Security in [this document](https://docs.oracle.com/html/A96524_01/c24privs.htm).  (@ibre5041)Nothing would have to be recompiled because the procedures run under the owner's privileges.  The user's (or his roles') privileges are only checked for whether they are allowed to run the procedure.
What am I missing?

Comment: AFAIK it is because object levels privs. to roles, together with public synonyms might affect visibility of objects. Theoretically this could lead to long dependency chain. (For example: Procedure uses table1(via public synonym), User has RoleA, RoleA has RoleB, table1 gets revoked from RoleB - get it mean that Procedure is invalid?). PS: this is just how I understand it.

Comment: @ibre5041 - does not matter (for recompiling) what privileges the user has.  The procedure would only have to be recompiled if the procedure **owner's** privileges change.  If the owner has access to table1, in your example, through RoleA, as you describe, then yes, the procedure would have to be recompiled.  But if the user's privileges to table1 change, the procedure does not have to be recompiled.  Even if the user does not have access to table 1, but he has access to run the procedure, owned by user all_ice, and all_ice has privileges to table1, the procedure should run ok.

Answer (score 0):

I'm think it is some historical heritage. When changing ROLE's object privs Oracle would have re-compile a lot of PL/SQL stored code. PS: you can also create something called "SCHEMA".

See [CREATE SCHEMA](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6014.htm) statement.