# Error user no priviledge when have a role in Oracle Database

Tags: database, oracle, package, roles, privileges

I want to ask about oracle database. So I have an user A and role B. In role B i have privilege to select any table, insert in table and etc. I have granted role B to user A. I have no problem if I run select and insert in usual. But I have a problem if I want to compile a package, it say that user A did not have privilege. I am sure that table or procedure inside package has been granted in role B. But it is still have error no priviledge. And one more if the privilege I put in user A it can run smoothly. But I want to put the privilege in Role B. How do I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Objects as packages, procedures, or functions need to be granted directly, and not through a role.

You have a very good explanation here

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1065832643319

And very good answers here

[Why doesn't PL/SQL respect privileges granted by Roles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30461235/why-doesnt-pl-sql-respect-privileges-granted-by-roles)