# Gather statistics for nested table

Tags: oracle, plsql

How can I gather statisics over nested table used in a package in Oracle. Is that possible?
I have done it over GTT but not able to do the same for nested table type object.

```sql
create or replace TYPE "TO_CNF_PYE_BSE_OBJ" AS OBJECT(
    FAP_INR_IDR        VARCHAR2(50)
);
create or replace TYPE "TO_CNF_PYE_BSE_TYP" AS TABLE OF TO_CNF_PYE_BSE_OBJ;
```

Inside code I am using collection to select records as nested table type from `to_cnf_bse_pye`:

```sql
CURSOR lv_cur (p_in_del_cri_days NUMBER) IS SELECT to_cnf_pye_bse_obj(fap_inr_idr) FROM to_cnf_pye_bse
```

Comment: Is the nested table an object type column of a database table? Or do you mean a PL/SQL collection? And how does your package use it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] as I do not think you are using the correct terminology. A `NESTED TABLE` is a SQL construct where a collection defined in the SQL scope is stored (nested) inside another table. A collection is a data type defined using the `CREATE TYPE` statement in the SQL scope or a `TYPE` statement in the PL/SQL scope and is a declaration of an in-memory data structure. From your previous comment, you appear to be talking about collections and not about nested tables.

Comment: Done the same. an you please say if I am using cursor in that way, is there a wayout to use gather statistics?

Comment: How are nested tables (or even collection data types) relevant to the question? You are only using the base object data type in the cursor and **NOT** the collection data type.

Comment: For future reference, please **edit your question** to add further details such as code or other improvements. The Comments section is reserved for comments, that is things which can be deleted without marring the question. In particular code samples are hard to read as comments, due to the small font size, poor layout and lack of formatting.

Comment: Duplicate of your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/q/66634096/1509264 that was closed as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30461235/why-doesnt-pl-sql-respect-privileges-granted-by-roles. Do not repeatedly ask the same question; if you think the first question should not have been closed then ask for it to have been reopened.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a nested table is just another table:

```sql
CREATE TYPE string_list AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20);

CREATE TABLE table_name (
  id   NUMBER,
  data string_list
) NESTED TABLE data STORE AS table_name__data;
```

Then you can do:

```sql
BEGIN
  DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS( 'SCHEMA_NAME', 'TABLE_NAME__DATA');
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f48f21657bd2419e4399a9ccdf5ceec2)*

---

## Update

> Inside code I am using collection to select records as nested table type from to_cnf_bse_pye:
>
> ```sql
> CURSOR lv_cur (p_in_del_cri_days NUMBER) IS SELECT to_cnf_pye_bse_obj(fap_inr_idr) FROM to_cnf_pye_bse
> ```

No, the [`DBMS_STATS` package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_STATS.html#GUID-01FAB8ED-E4A3-4C3E-8FE2-88717DCDDA06) does not have any method of gathering statistics on a cursor.

However, you can gather statistics on the underlying `to_cnf_pye_bse` table.

*(As an aside, you are not using the `TO_CNF_PYE_BSE_TYP` collection data type; your cursor is getting the base object type so nested tables appear to be entirely irrelevant to the question.)*

Comment: I dont want to use nested table in this form but rather as :CURSOR lv_cur (p_in_del_cri_days NUMBER) IS
        SELECT to_cnf_pye_bse_obj(fap_inr_idr)
  FROM to_cnf_pye_bse

Comment: @TBose See my comment on your question about using the correct terminology. You asked about nested tables so I answered about nested tables; if you mean something else then you need to give a [MRE] (in your question and not in comments) to explain what you are talking about.